# How to create span on new line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple spans inside of a div but all are at same line. I want to write every span on new line.
Here is the html code:

```css
.divContent {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8
}

.divContent span {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4D575D;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="divContent">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
```

Now the result of this code is:
Span 1 Span 2 Span 3

But I want

Span 1

Span 2

Span 3

Comment: By default, `<span>` is an inline element. If you don't want an inline element, don't use `<span>`.

Comment: @Rob in this case the container is a flex container so it's ok as `span` and `div` will behave the same

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer in case there is one that solves your issue, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Change the [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) to `column`:

```css
.divContent {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*added this */
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center; /*added this if you want centring*/
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8
}

.divContent span {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4D575D;
  margin: 0 3px
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="divContent">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect using the `display` propery that you've defined in `.divContent` class in your stylesheet.

```css
.divContent {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid; /* changed here */
  /* YOU CAN ALSO USE inline-grid HERE */
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8
}
.divContent span {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4D575D;
  margin: 0 3px
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="divContent">
        <span>Span 1</span>
        <span>Span 2</span>
        <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another *flexbox* way of doing it includes `flex-wrap: wrap` and `flex-basis` with the *value* of your choice (explanation below):

```css
.divContent {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables wrapping of flex-items (default: "nowrap") */
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8;
}

.divContent span {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5.99px); /* initial width; needs to be at least 50.01% to make it work (if there are no left/right margins), else "calc(50% - 5.99px)" is enough in this case (- 2 * 3px left/right margin = - 6px, so a little bit more to push the others and force them to wrap) */
  flex-basis: 100%; /* but for simplicity's sake just make it 100% so they take full parent's width */
  text-align: center; /* added */
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4D575D;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="divContent">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an break tag also work!!!

```
   <div id="content" class="divContent">
    <span>Span 1</span> <br>
    <span>Span 2</span> <br>
    <span>Span 3</span> <br>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add display: block; in span

```css
.divContent {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8
}
.divContent span {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4D575D;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="divContent">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using flex, so using display: block in the child elements will not have the desired outcome. The flex direction of the parent element is what should be changed